# linux virtual server with io issues - deadline vs noop elevator

Tags: linux, mysql, virtualization, performance, linux-kernel

I have a Linux virtual server experiencing IO issues from MySQL.

Would using the deadline io elevator possibly be preferable to noop in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, but it depends on your virtualization platform. This is easy to test (change the I/O elevator and apply the same workload), but I'd suspect lower-level issues... E.g. Your storage back-end or something at the hypervisor level.

Answer (score 0):

noop should be the best scheduler in a VM, with deadline usually the most effective on the hosts. But before any advice is given, you need to elaborate on your setup, maybe you've missed something much more fundamental